# Zend Newbie Issue with Controllers

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I have a front controller that works. I wrote a login controller called AuthController.php. It is configured with the appropriate code inside. My problem is when I go to /auth I get a 404. It seems to be some sort of routing problem.

My auth controller is called AuthController.php and the top part of it looks like this:

```
class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}


public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if ($this->_process($form->getValues())) {
                // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

and of course there are protected functions below that handle other things. In Zend, when you create a new controller, doesn't just its existence (like in CodeIgniter) mean it should be available? Or do I have to add it to a routing table somewhere?

EDIT: Here is my Apache Vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      new.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot    /www/htdocs/zend/public
<Directory /www/htdocs/zend/public>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There's the default routing which is `[/module]/controller/action` If you don't specify the action, then it will try to execute the `indexAction`. It's hard to tell you why it's not working by the provided code. If the 404 is not an exception, but the server 404 response, then your `mod_rewrite`/`htaccess` is not properly configured.

Comment: I checked the .htaccess and it looks right. Perhaps apache is not configured correctly. This is not on my server so I will check that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Apache? You should look at your virtual host configuration. If it is not setup correctly, you will only ever get the default index page displayed, as Apache won't pass the routing on to Zend. Please share the virtual host configuration if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled (if on Apache)
2. Make sure the AuthController.php file is in the default module (the same one you
   have put your IndexController.php into)
3. Check the httpd.conf file is set in Apache to allow overides (so htaccess will work) - this might be apache.conf if using a debian box with debian squeeze - not sure about other linux types though.

If all of this is correct then it should work just fine.

Comment: I double checked everything and there was a typo in htaccess. Everything is fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try creating another controller or testController and then try to access like /test if it gives errors then there might be a problem. if it works then change your Auth conroller and name it with different class name

Answer (score 1):

I myself am a newbie to zend, In my experience 404 errors have occured due either

htaccess was not configured(as mentioned by Keyne in the comments)

or

There was no view associated with the the controller/action either it was not created by me altogether or there was some kind of typo in the folder/action/view  filenames.

So ensure that the above 2 are not the cases.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but what does 'in the default module' mean? AuthController.conf is currently in the same directory as IndexController.php if that is what you mean.